# all deque elements using data classes

Tags: python, deque

I'm having problems of getting my code to work. I'm trying to get all deque elements using a data class but it's no working. Everything in the main Deque is right but their is something wrong with the class.

Main Deque

```
import Deque as deq

# Program starts
empty = deq.Deque()     # An empty deque
deque = deq.Deque()     # To be filled

for i in range(1, 11):
  deque.add_last(i)
print(deque.to_string())
print("Size:", deque.size)

for i in range(11, 21):
deque.add_first(i)
print(deque.to_string())
print("Size:", deque.size)

 print("\nget_last():", deque.get_last())
 print("get_last() on empty deque:", empty.get_last())

 print("\nget_first():", deque.get_first())
 print("get_first() on empty deque:", empty.get_first())

 print("\nremove_first():", deque.remove_first())
 print("remove_first() on empty deque:", empty.remove_first())

 print("\nremove_last():", deque.remove_last())
 print("remove_last() on empty deque:", empty.remove_last())

 print(deque.to_string())
 print("Size:", deque.size)

 print("\nTest to remove all elements")
 temp = deq.Deque()
 for i in range(100, 106):
   temp.add_first(i)
 print("After adding elements:", temp.to_string())
 while temp.size > 0:
   temp.remove_last()
 print("After removing all elements:", temp.to_string())
 print("Size:", temp.size)
```

and this is the class Deque

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any



@dataclass
class Node:
value: int = None
nxt: Any = None  # Any since Node not properly defined at this point


@dataclass
class Deque:
   head: Node = None      # First node in queue
   tail: Node = None      # Last node in queue
   size: int = 0


 def add_last(self, n):
    new = Node(n, None)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new
        self.tail = new
    else:
        self.tail.nxt = new
        self.tail = new
    self.size += 1

def to_string(self):
    s = "{ "
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        s += str(node.value) + " "
        node = node.nxt
    s += "}"
    return s

def add_first(self, n):
    new = Node(n, None)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new
        self.tail = new
    else:
        self.tail.nxt = new
        self.tail = new
    self.size += 1

def get_last(self):
    if self.tail is None:
        print("Get can't be applied on an empty list")
        return None
    else:
        return self.tail.value


def get_first(self):
    pass


def remove_first(self):
    pass


def remove_last(self):
    pass
```

The output I'm getting

```
None
Size: 0
None
Size: 0

get_last(): None
get_last() on empty deque: None

get_first(): None
get_first() on empty deque: None

remove_first(): None
remove_first() on empty deque: None

remove_last(): None
remove_last() on empty deque: None
None
Size: 0

Test to remove all elements
After adding elements: None
After removing all elements: None
Size: 0
```

and the output I'm supposed to get

```
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
Size: 10
{ 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
Size: 20

get_last(): 10
You can't access an empty queue
get_last() on empty deque: None

get_first(): 20
You can't access an empty queue
get_first() on empty deque: None

remove_first(): 20
You can't access an empty queue
remove_first() on empty deque: None

remove_last(): 10
You can't access an empty queue
remove_last() on empty deque: None
{ 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }
Size: 18

Test to remove all elements
After adding elements: { 105 104 103 102 101 100 }
After removing all elements: { }
Size: 0
```

I haven't finished the entire code however, I can't start without def add_first def add_last. Does anyone know what's wrong with the Deque class code? Would really appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your Deque class. In the add_first and add_last methods, you are not properly linking the new node to the rest of the list.

In the add_first method, you need to set the new node's next field to point to the current head of the list. Then, you need to set the head field of the Deque to point to the new node.

In the add_last method, you need to set the new node's next field to point to None, since it will be the last node in the list. Then, you need to set the tail field of the Deque to point to the new node.

Here is the fixed code for the Deque class. I hope this helps.

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

```
@dataclass
class Node:
value: int = None
nxt: Any = None  # Any since Node not properly defined at this point


@dataclass
class Deque:
   head: Node = None      # First node in queue
   tail: Node = None
```